# Encoding numbers to words

Tags: java, algorithm

My task is is writing a program that finds, for a given phone number, all
possible encodings by words and prints them. 
This is my mapping from letters to digits:

```
E | J N Q | R W X | D S Y | F T | A M | C I V | B K U | L O P | G H Z
e | j n q | r w x | d s y | f t | a m | c i v | b k u | l o p | g h z
0 |   1   |   2   |   3   |  4  |  5  |   6   |   7   |   8   |   9
```

Also I have dictionary.txt file with all possible words.
So if my program gets number 562482 as input then output will be:

```
562482: mir Tor
```

because I have in my dictionary.txt words 'mir' and 'Tor'.

Firstly, I decided to create special structure for quick searching the word in dictionary and use for that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> bucketedWords = new HashMap<>()
```

where key is number of each word in dictionary and value is a list of all words in dictionary with such number. This structure is initialized after starting my program.
Example of entry:

`key: 562 values: [mir, mix]`

So I can search quickly in my dictionary and receive all possible words by numbers.

Now I'm curious about the second part.
Every input number has 2^(n-1) combinations of consecutive substrings.
I split input number to a list of such combinations and check each entry in my bucketWord dictionary. 
If input number's length becomes long then I spend to much time looking for all combinations of substrings. Is it right way for solving such problem or there are better solution for my task?

more information about the task [here](http://poj.org/problem?id=1798)

**EDIT**

As SpiderPig advised me I've used recursion but with small change which helps me to find words with subsequent digits:

```
private List<List<String>> _findEncodings(String number, int startAt, boolean isNumber) {
    LinkedList<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<>();

    if (startAt == number.length()) {
        result.add(new LinkedList<String>());
        return result;
    }
    for (int endAt = startAt + 1; endAt <= number.length(); endAt++) {
        List<String> words = bucketedWords.get(number.substring(startAt,
                endAt));
        if (words != null) {
            List<List<String>> encodings = null;
            if((endAt - startAt == 1) && (words.size() == 1) && (isNumeric(words.get(0)))){
                if(isNumber){
                    continue;
                }
                encodings = _findEncodings(number, endAt, true);
            }else{
                encodings = _findEncodings(number, endAt, false);
            }
            for (String word : words) {
                for (List<String> encoding : encodings) {
                    List<String> enc = new LinkedList<>(encoding);
                    enc.add(0, word);
                    result.add(enc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public List<List<String>> findEncodings(String number) {
    return _findEncodings(number, 0, false);
}

public boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Also I've added numbers in my buckets. That's working in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive backtracking algorithm should be faster since it doesn't go through all combinations but only the ones that look promising.

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> bucketedWords = new HashMap<>();

private static List<List<String>> _findEncodings(String number, int startAt) {
  LinkedList<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<>();
  if(startAt == number.length()) {
    result.add(new LinkedList<String>());
    return result;
  }
  for(int endAt = startAt + 1; endAt <= number.length(); endAt++) {
    List<String> words = bucketedWords.get(number.substring(startAt, endAt));
    if(words != null) {
      List<List<String>> encodings = _findEncodings(number, endAt);
      for(String word: words) {
        for(List<String> encoding: encodings) {
          List<String> enc = new LinkedList<>(encoding);
          enc.add(0, word);
          result.add(enc);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

private static List<List<String>> findEncodings(String number) {
  return _findEncodings(number, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  bucketedWords.put("562", Arrays.asList("mir", "Mix"));
  bucketedWords.put("482", Arrays.asList("Tor"));
  bucketedWords.put("10", Arrays.asList("je"));
  bucketedWords.put("78", Arrays.asList("Bo\""));
  bucketedWords.put("35", Arrays.asList("da"));

  System.out.println(findEncodings("562482"));
  System.out.println(findEncodings("107835"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's better solution. Also I've made little change in this code for cases when two subsequent digits in the converted word.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a trie instead of a Map.  The Trie understands the sequence of numbers one at a time.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

In this case it is O(max(len(word))) which for phone numbers is O(7) ~ O(1)